# Python regex matching only if digit

Tags: python, regex

Given the regex and the word below I want to match the part after the - (which can also be a _ or space) only if the part after the delimiter is a digit and nothing comes after it (I basically want to to be a number and number only). I am using group statements but it just doesn't seem to work right. It keeps matching the 3 at the beginning (or the 1 at the end if I modify it a bit). How do I achieve this (by using grouping) ?

Target word: `BR0227-3G1`

Regex: `([A-Z]*\s?[0-9]*)[\s_-]*([1-9][1-9]*)`

It should not match 3G1, G1 , 1G

It should match only pure numbers like 3,10, 2 etc.

Here is also a helper web site for evaluating the regex: http://www.pythonregex.com/

More examples:

It should match:

```
BR0227-3
BR0227 3
BR0227_3
```

into groups `(BR0227) (3)`

It should only match `(BR0227)` for

```
BR0227-3G1
BR0227-CS
BR0227
BR0227-
```

Comment: I'm confused .. can you provide more example inputs and outputs (e.g. examples of what should match/be captured and not match)?

Comment: @Cemre Check my answer, and let me know if that is what you're looking for.

Comment: @OscarMederos I try your regex with BR0227-3G1 using the website I have provided and it matches `(u'G', u'1')`

Comment: @Cemre Sorry, wrong regex. Updated my answer now.

Comment: are each of them separated by newline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use

```
re.findall('^([A-Z]*\s?[0-9]*)[\s_-]*([1-9][1-9]*$)?', str)
```

Each string starts with the first group and ends with the last group, so the `^` and `$` groups can assist in capture.  The `$` at the end requires *all* numbers to be captured, but it's optional so the first group can still be captured.

Comment: This one seem to work great. I guess the `?` was the crucial part I was missing

Comment: @Cemre by the way if all of the words are in one string you may need to use `re.MULTILINE` with `.findall`.  If you're iterating, you can use `.match` I think

Answer (score 1):

Since you want the start and (possible) end of the word in groups, then do this:

```
r'\b([A-Z0-9]+)(?:[ _-](\d+))?\b'
```

This will put the first part of the word in the first group, and optionally the remainder in the second group. The second group will be `None` if it didn't match.

Comment: If not just match the character after

Comment: This is the best answer, since you are including the separator in the optional match. You should remove everything else and just leave the update. Also, remember, it could be `-`, `_` or a space (the separator).

Answer (score 0):

This should match anything followed by '-', ' ', or '_' with only digits after it.

```
(.*)[- _](\d+)
```

Comment: If the string is `BR0227-CS` this matches nothing (it should stil match BR0227)

Comment: Ah i see. Missed that requirment